# Compatibility of ERC20 Token ICO with Parity Client-how exactly does it work

Tags: parity, contract-deployment, erc-20, ico, parity-wallet

Compatibility of ERC20 Token ICO with Parity Client-how exactly does it work?

i am struggling, how do I get the erc20 token after a contribution with Parity? Do I have to go to the "contracts" menu, or the "token registry" menu within Parity to add manually the custom erc20 tokens, or does everything happen automatically, and after the ICO I will see directly my new erc20 token? 
How does Parity allow me to "Possess" the tokens , so that I can for example transact them to an exchange for trading , or to another wallet?

Anybody who did an actual erc20 ICO with Parity, here who can help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Initially your parity wallet doesn't know about the token your getting through the crowd sale. So, After getting the ERC20 token from the company, Enter their token contract address in watch token section and click ok button. After this process your parity wallet can display the token balance.

Comment: hi thanks! ok, after I see it or "watch" it: how can i actually "possess" it and transact it further to another wallet, etc.?

Comment: Once your wallet understand the ERC20 token, you can send it to another wallet just like ether. While sending you have to choose ERC20 token instead of ether.